# How to call a function from an imported component in another file in React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, import, onclick

I'm currently trying to hook up a button in my homepage to go to another link, and I want to make use of some functions from another file. Currently, the functions I want to use are in a `SettingsMenu.tsx file` and the component looks like this:

```
export class SettingsMenu extends Component<
  SettingsMenuProps,
  SettingsMenuState
> {
  constructor(props: SettingsMenuProps) {
    //Lots of code 
  }

  gotoExternalLink = (e: React.MouseEvent, url: string) => {
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer');
    this.hideSettingsMenu(e);
  };


//More code 

}
```

And in my homepage, I've already done `import SettingsMenu from './SettingsMenu'` and attempted to hook up my button wiith the `gotoExternalLink` function, which I'm having difficulty doing. I have tried the following:

```
Button variant="contained" className="support-button" 
          onClick={gotoExternalLink(e,"https://app.clovergive.com/App/Form/c226e457-5e64-4f75-8cbb-e8cba99138f4" )}>
          Support Us
        </Button>
```

Can anyone provide some support or help?

Comment: Try `onClick={e => gotoExternalLink(e,"https://app.clovergive.com/App/Form/c226e457-5e64-4f75-8cbb-e8cba99138f4" )}`

Comment: hmm...the code "cannot find name gotoExternalLink"

Answer (score 0):

Standing at one component and calling a method from another component is not the way React data flow works.

If you simply want to go to external link, you could extract that logic into a utils file and call it in each event handler.

```
//in utils.ts
export const goToExternalLinkUtil = (url: string) => {
  window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer');
}

// in HomePage.tsx
<Button variant="contained" 
    className="support-button" 
    onClick={() => { gotoExternalLinkUtil("https://app.clovergive.com/App/Form/c226e457-5e64-4f75-8cbb-e8cba99138f4");}
 >
   Support Us
 </Button>
```

In case you would like to go to extarnal link and then hide the setting menu, you might want to [lift up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) of `isSettingMenuOpen` to the nearest ancestor of `SettingMenu` and `Homepage`.

Another suggestion is using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to manage all the state in one centralized place.